# How to fix Content Security Policy for Stripe in a React app

Tags: html, reactjs, stripe-payments, content-security-policy, meta-tags

I have not worked with Content Security Policy before. I'm getting the following error when redirecting users to Stripe Checkout.

[image: Error Image]

Even after adding meta tags to index.html, I'm still getting error. Here is what I'm doing :

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
         default-src *; 
         style-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline'; 
         img-src https://*.stripe.com;
         script-src * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com 'unsafe-inline'; 
         connect-src  * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com  ; 
         frame-src * 'self'  https://checkout.stripe.com ; "
    />
```

Stripe docs : https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

What is the proper way to write Content Security Policy and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The screenshot says you've got duplicate `report-uri` directives, but there are none in the code you've shown. Are you sure you're not already setting the CSP header somewhere else?

Comment: @RichardDeeming I'm using Helmet. Does it bring any sort of CSP along with it.

Comment: Assuming it's [this project](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet), it looks like it does include a CSP header by default. But it doesn't look like it adds a `report-uri` directive unless you've provided one via the options.